# How to find if a DOM element is attached with some Javascript or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

For some testing purpose I want to traverse the DOM and want to find if that particular element is bound to some JS. I am using jQuery. I tried with `$('selector').data()` but with no avail. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: define "bound". Bound to what?, event handlers, data? ...

Answer (score 1):

For testing, you could use [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) Much better than any other tool I have used. You can get it for chrome [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pbmmieigblcbldgdokdjpioljjninaim)